# Finding which preference is selected from ListPreference

Tags: java, android

I have a List Preference in the Preferences.xml folder. In my code I want to see which preference was selected from the List Preference, and use it in a particular condition. Is there any methods that will check for this? If not can anybody give me a pointer in the right direction.

Thanks Very Much,

XcutionX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be assigning the preference a key in your XML using `android:key="pref_mykey"`.

You then retrieve the value like so:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String myPref = sharedPref.getString("pref_mykey", "default_value");
```

For more information I would suggest reading the [Settings](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html) guide, specifically [Reading Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#ReadingPrefs).

Comment: @Tanis.7x...It seems that I have declared it correctly. I'm trying to set check if it is equal, how would I do this in an if loop? right now i Have if(selection.equals(R.string.data)) {, but its not running correctly.

Comment: That's because `R.string.data` is a reference to a String, not an actual String. To get the actual String you need to call `getResources().getString(R.string.data)`.